# I'm trying to get the autoinstall working for Ubuntu server 22.04 but the installer doesn't seem to pick up the instructions

Tags: server, autoinstall

I'm trying to get the most basic Ubuntu Server headless installation scenario working. I  trimmed my user-data yaml file down to the bare minimum.

```
#cloud-config
version: 1
identity:
   hostname: headless2204
   username: batman
   password: topsecret
   package_upgrade: false

ssh:
   install-server: yes
   allow-pw: yes

Together with an empty meta-data file I placed it into the /nocloud-net folder.
```

As for grub.cfg, I added:

```
menuentry "Headless Ubuntu Server Installation" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux /casper/vmlinuz  quiet autoinstall ds=nocloud-net\;s=/cdrom/nocloud-net/ ---
    initrd /casper/initrd.gz
}
```

The only shortcut I've taken was that I popped up an Ubuntu Desktop VM and launched Cubic instead of CLI tools and xorriso. Is there any difference between them? Cubic seems to be doing exactly the same thing.

My custom image boots just fine, the updated grub.cfg works, however the Ubuntu installer doesn't seem to pick up the autoinstall config. It just works the standard way. When I switch to a different terminal session (Ctrl+F2) during the installation to check the logs, there is nothing autoinstall related. I could only find cloud-init stuff but nothing helpful there.

Do you have any ideas about fixing or debugging it?

Comment: To start, your `user-data` file does not have an `autoinstall` section.  Compare your `user-data` file to any working example.

Comment: Andrew thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, adding an autoinstall line to the config made no difference.

Comment: Got it working:

user-data:

'''none
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version:  1
  identity:
     hostname: headless2204
     username: batman
     password: <mkpasswd -m sha-512 topsecret>
  ssh:
     install-server: yes
     allow-pw: yes
'''
grub.cfg:

'''none
menuentry "Headless Ubuntu Server Installation" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux /casper/vmlinuz   "ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/nocloud/" quiet autoinstall ---
    initrd /casper/initrd.gz
}
'''
Would be nice to see the documentation updated.

Comment: Could you please add your comment as an answer and checkmark it? As a comment, the formatting is lost. Additionally, could you add an explanation of what solved the issue and where you found the info?

Comment: @mpboden It is not possible for us to change comments to answers as moderators.  OP has to do that.  (Please don't use flags for that)

Comment: @ThomasWard Gotcha. Didn’t know that. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to format it nicely:

user-data yaml:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: headless2204
    username: batman
    password: <mkpasswd -m sha-512 topsecret> #the original manual stated an unencrypted password which doesn't work
    package_upgrade: false
  ssh:
    install-server: yes
    allow-pw: yes
```

Together with an empty meta-data file I placed it into the /nocloud-net folder. Now I use just /nocloud. Don't think the folder name is important though.

And here's my grub.cfg menu entry for the autoinstall (just insert it before the first menu entry "Try or Install Ubuntu Server")

```
menuentry "Headless Ubuntu Server Installation" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz "ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/nocloud/" quiet autoinstall  ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.gz   
}
```

Documentation and most tutorials list the config path unquoted. But somehow it was the quotes that did the magic for me: "ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/nocloud/"

However, there's more witchcraft to this: I only got it working on 22.04. Still trying to figure out how to get it to work on the 20.04. I will post this as a separate question. The only visible difference I found so far was a different grub.cfg file structure.

PS: corrected the user-data by adding the autoinstall that I missed while copying and formatting the post. Thanks, mpboden!

Comment: Your _user-data_ and _grub.cfg_ files look in essence the same. In your comment above, however, I see that you used the `autoinstall` keyword. Was that neglected in your answer here?

Comment: Corrected, thank you very much for noticing, mpboden!